# How to validate SPPeoplePicker with bootstrap-validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm trying to validated SPPeoplePicker control with [1000hz bootstrap-validator](https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-fields) but it doesn't seems to work. Can someone help me to validate it?

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="myPicker" class="form-group has-feedback">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label for="peoplePickerDiv" class="control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                <div id="peoplePickerDiv"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
            <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

TypeScript:

```
$('#peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan_HiddenInput').attr('data-user', 'user');
$('#aspnetForm').validator({

        custom: {

            user: function ($el) {

                var peoplePickerElement: SPClientPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict['peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan'];
                var user: ISPClientPeoplePickerEntity[] = peoplePickerElement.GetAllUserInfo();

                if (user[0].IsResolved == true) {

                    $('myPicker').attr('has-success');
                    return "IT WORKS";

                }
                else if (user[0].IsResolved == false) {

                    $('myPicker').attr('has-danger');
                    return "Invalid User";
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please add your error message ?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. At least there is not one in the console.The control itself is working fine. The problem is that the validator is not working when I select an user. You know light up green if there is a resolved user in the control and red if there is no user or not a valid one.

Comment: lol i just saw that I'm missing "#" in  $('myPicker'). I'm gonna test it now and will post update.

Comment: So you may have an error "undefined has no attribute named 'attr'"... No ?

Comment: Nope there was no error. After changing it to $('#myPicker') the code still deosnt seem to do anything. The field lights up green no matter what i type in.

Comment: is this the right way to get the PeoplePicker object using typescript?

      `var peoplePickerElement: SPClientPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict['peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan'];`

Comment: The following code seems to work in javascript `var peoplePickerElement = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;`

Comment: You test `if (user[0].IsResolved == false)` after `if (user[0].IsResolved == true)`. I don't know what is your IsResolved attribute, but maybe adding a log in the third case will help you... ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achiev my goal by writing custom function for validating the ClientPicker. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
    <div id="myPicker" class="row has-feedback">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label for="peoplePickerDiv" class="control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                <div id="peoplePickerDiv"></div>
            </div>
            <span id="ppFeedIcon"class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
            <span id="ppFeedMsg" class="help-block with-errors"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Typescript:

```
    var peoplePickerElement: SPClientPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict['peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan'];

    $('#myPicker').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved DOMSubtreeModified', function () {

         if ( peoplePickerElement.GetAllUserInfo().length == 0) {
            $('#myPicker').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
            $('#ppFeedIcon').addClass("glyphicon-remove").removeClass("glyphicon-ok");
            $('#ppFeedMsg').html('Invalid user.');
        }

       else if (peoplePickerElement.GetAllUserInfo().length > 0 ) {
            $('#myPicker').addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
            $('#ppFeedIcon').addClass("glyphicon-ok").removeClass("glyphicon-remove");   
            $('#ppFeedMsg').html("");
        }
    });
```